# jQuery slider not sliding

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider

[Here is the code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FJTpe/)

I guess there is something wrong with the slide function:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
          var input = this.next(':input');
          input.val(input.attr('alt') + ui.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.next()` method is a jQuery method so you need to use it in reference to a jQuery object. So just wrap `this` inside of a jQuery constructor.

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
    var input = $(this).next(':input');
    input.val(input.attr('alt') + ui.value);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcr9h/)